# select from table where condition like %{list of values}%

Tags: mysql, join, select, stored-procedures, subquery

I want to get all rows in table, which column "comment" can contains a value of another table:

row name in table T1 contains a list of names.

row comment in table T2 compound a string, one name can be embedded in comment.

I tried to execute the next PLSQL code:

```
BEGIN

SET @SearchCriteria = (SELECT * FROM names);
    
SET @SearchCriteria = '%' + @SearchCriteria + '%';
    
SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE comment LIKE @SearchCriteria;

END
```

but it returns: subquery returns more than 1 row

Also, I executed the below procedure, but I didn't get any result:

```
BEGIN 
DECLARE nm VARCHAR(16);
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT nm FROM names;

OPEN cur1;
   
   read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO nm;
    set @name = '%'+nm+'%';
  
    SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE comment LIKE @name;
    
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE cur1; 
END
```

The previous code demands a long time to get result, so I changed value of max_execution_time in phpmyadmin.conf.

**MYSQL version: 5.6.17**

How can I get the correct result?

Comment: This is a faq. Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a single query:

```
select t.*
from ticket t
where exists (
    select 1
    from names n
    where t.comment like concat('%', n.nm, '%')
)
```

This brings all rows from table `ticket` whose `comment` contains a `nm` that can be found in table `names`.